# asp.net mvc razor Get integer part of string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I have a property string in my model with values like "USD 32", "E 123" ... and I need the integer part of those strings ("32", "123", ...)

```
@{
    var number = @Model.MyStringProperty;
}
```

ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this in Razor, or in the View at all.  This belongs squarely on the Model.

For example, let's assume the property looks like this:

```
public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
```

Then what you would do is add another property to transform the value from this one:

```
public int MyStringPropertyAsInt
{
    get
    {
        // string manipulation logic goes here
        // possibly something like this:
        var numericString = new string(MyStringProperty.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
        var integerValue = 0;
        int.TryParse(numericString, out integerValue);
        return integerValue;
    }
}
```

Then in the View, you'd simply reference that property:

```
@Model.MyStringPropertyAsInt
```

The point is, you shouldn't have a lot of server-side code blocks in the View.  Ideally all of the data manipulation and logic is on the Model, and the View simply binds to that Model's exposed data properties.

Comment: Looking at the examples given in the question, it would be worth splitting the original string value into two properties.  One string property for the currency code, and an integer field for the amount (though if you are dealing with money a Decimal would be better).

Comment: @PervezChoudhury: Agreed.  Though he did specify the "integer part of the string."  The more strongly-typed and structured the data, the better.  Ideally the "units" and the "amount" should be separate data altogether.